# Provide class to be decorated by Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

In pre 1.0 versions of the draper gem we were able to use the `decorates` method explicitly specifying the class to be decorated (e.g. when the class is namespaced):

```
MyClassDecorator < Draper::Base
   decorates :my_class, :class => Namespace::MyClass
   ...
```

Now (draper 1.3) `decorates` does not accept additional parameters. 
But just omitting the :class option leads to `"uninitialized constant MyClass"`.

How do we decorate classes whose class names cannot be deducted by draper automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/587

It is possible to specify the class instead of a symbol:

```
MyClassDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates Namespace::MyClass
  ...
```